# Let's get critical: Sep 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Russian Language & Usage Stack Exchange](http://russian.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://russian.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [past tense without л](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2486/past-tense-without-%d0%bb)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Representing long vowels in Russian Cyrillic](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2481/representing-long-vowels-in-russian-cyrillic)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Numbers ending in 1](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2491/numbers-ending-in-1)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Иметь vs у меня for physical things](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/%d0%98%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c-vs-%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f-for-physical-things)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Certain words supposedly in Russian that I can't verify!](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2517/certain-words-supposedly-in-russian-that-i-cant-verify)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Famous tongue-twister which is pronounced in parties](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/famous-tongue-twister-which-is-pronounced-in-parties)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Как правильно пишется фраза «почему ? неизвестно»](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2503/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0-%c2%ab%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%c2%bb)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [The difference in usage amongst these verbs and adverbs?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2506/the-difference-in-usage-amongst-these-verbs-and-adverbs)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to say "житель Крымска" and not to confuse it with "житель Крыма"?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2525/how-to-say-%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%9a%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%bc%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-and-not-to-confuse-it-with-%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%9a%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b0)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Talking about perfective and imperfective verbs](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2537/talking-about-perfective-and-imperfective-verbs)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)